# How can place search icon on right side?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery mobile 1.4.2. I need to shift the search icon from left to right and how can I avoid the clear button appearing.

```
<div data-role=page">
    <form method="post">
        <input name="search" id="search" value="" placeholder="Buscar" type="search" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Buscar'">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: A fiddle will help a lot

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/BCGC2/1/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/BCGC2/2/

CSS

```
.ui-input-search:after {
    right:0.75em;
    left: auto;
}
.ui-input-search input {
    padding-left:0.75em;
}
```

Comment: That moved the search icon to the right, but didn't prevent the clear icon from showing on the right under the search icon when text was entered.

Comment: Sorry missed that part. here's an updated one: http://jsfiddle.net/BCGC2/3/ Let me know fi that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

@MarioD beat me to it. If you don't want the clear button to show, just set it's display: none

http://jsfiddle.net/5CgJ2/

```
.ui-input-search:after {
    left: auto;
    right: .75em;
}

.ui-input-search input {
    padding-left: .75em;
}

.ui-input-search.ui-input-has-clear .ui-btn.ui-input-clear, .ui-input-text.ui-input-has-clear .ui-btn.ui-input-clear {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: is it possible to make search box icon clickable?(like a submit)

Comment: Since the search icon is a pseudo element, it does not exist in the DOM. Therefore, you cannot attach a click event. Given that you're going to be targeting a mobile platform, it may be difficult for a user to accurately press the icon anyway. It'd probably be better to rely on the devices keyboard to perform the form submission rather than a UI element on the screen.